# What version of MongoDB is used by Azure CosmosDB? How can I check the version?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to figure out what version of MongoDB is used by CosmosDB?

Tried checking out azure cosmosdb portal for more information but there is no specific version mentioned on it.

Comment: CosmoDB is not MongoDB. So your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rthomas529 I understand that now. Also, there is no harm in asking a question. If I knew it before hand I wouldn't have posted a question at first place. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: To know which version of the MongoDB wire protocol is supported by the cosmos DB, you can connect to the cosmos DB  from robo mongo 3T client or mongo shell and execute [`db.version()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.version/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support):

> **The Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB is compatible with MongoDB
>   server version 3.2 by default**. The supported operators and any
>   limitations or exceptions are listed below. Features or query
>   operators added in MongoDB version 3.4 are currently available as a
>   preview feature. Any client driver that understands these protocols
>   should be able to connect to Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB.

Comment: Cosmos DB isn't actually MongoDB. So there is no "version 3.2" of MongoDB. Compatibility is at an API-level. Important distinction that I don't think is explicitly conveyed by this answer (and the OPs question sounds like they are assuming MongoDB is the engine running behind Cosmos DB).

Comment: It has been updated to support v4.0 [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-40)

Answer (score 2):

In modern Azure Portal UI they display the version of your Cosmos DB in the Overview section:
[image: Cosmos DB Overview section]